# Zip the contents of a folder in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am trying to zip the contents of a Folder in SSIS, there are files and folders in the source folder and I need to zip them all individually. I can get the files to zip fine my problem is the folders.

I have to use 7.zip to create the zipped packages.

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial. I haven't been able to implement any of the samples that I have found.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Execute Task]
This is how I have configured it.

Its easy to configure but the trick is in constructing the **Arguments**. Though you see the **Arguments** as static in the screenshot, its actually coming from a variable and that variable is set in the **Arguments expression** of Execute Process Task.

I presume you will have this Execute Process task in a **For Each File Ennumerator** with **Traverse SubFolders** checked.

Once you have this basic setup in place, all you need to do is work on building the arguments to do the zipping, how you want them. A good place to find all the command line arguments is [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).

Finally, the only issue I ran into was not providing a working directory in the command line arguments for 7zip. The package used to run fine on my dev environment but used to fail when running on the server via a SQL job. This was because 7zip didn't have access to the 'Temp' folder on the SQL Server, which it uses by default as the 'working directory'. I got round this problem by specifying the 'working directory as follows at the end of the command line arguments, using the **-ws** switch:

For e.g:

a -t7z DestinationFile.7z SourceFile **-wS:YourTempDirectoryToWhichTheSQLAgentHasRights**