# Creating a Zip Folder using C#

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to create a zip folder with some files in it by getting the path from the server and using the vjslib.dll library

The code fails at  `ZipOutputStream outf = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));`

The error i get **A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in vjslib.dll**

```
using System;
    using System.Data;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using java.util.zip;
    using java.io;

    namespace s1.csproj
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
        public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
        {


            enum ScriptResults
            {
                Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
                Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
            };




            public void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    ZipFiles();
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                }

            }

            public void ZipFiles()
            {
                string xlsFileName = Dts.Variables["User::ZipFileMask"].Value.ToString();
                string ZipFileName = Dts.Variables["User::ZipFileName"].Value.ToString();
                string ZipFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::ZipFilePath"].Value.ToString();

                //Delete the zip file
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(ZipFilePath + ZipFileName))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(ZipFilePath + ZipFileName);

                string FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::ZipFilePath"].Value.ToString() ;

                // These are the files to include in the ZIP file            
                string[] FileNames = Directory.GetFiles(FilePath, xlsFileName);

                // Create a buffer for reading the files
                sbyte[] buff = new sbyte[1024];

                try
                {
                    // Create the ZIP file
                    String outFilename = ZipFilePath + ZipFileName;
                    ZipOutputStream outf = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));


                    // Compress the files
                    for (int i = 0; i < FileNames.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string strsourcefile = FileNames[i];
                        FileInputStream inx = new FileInputStream(strsourcefile);
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileNames[i]);
                        string strzipentry = filename;
                        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(strzipentry);
                        outf.putNextEntry(ze);
                        sbyte[] buffer = new sbyte[1024];
                        int len;

                        while ((len = inx.read(buff)) > 0)
                        {
                            outf.write(buff, 0, len);
                        }

                        outf.closeEntry();
                        inx.close();

                    }
                    outf.close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Curious, why use a Java library when there is System.IO.Compression.GZipStream? Does it not work in SSIS?

Comment: @R.Richards I use vjslib.dll library for security but if you can create the same script with ought java library i can give it a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my attempt using a couple of approaches. One using GZipStream, and the other using ZipArchive. Both of these are in the System.IO.Compression namespace. The ZipArchive requires a reference to the System.IO.Compression.FileSystem assembly to get the extension methods needed in its example. See the comments in the code, too.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace SOTesting
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                // I couldn't get the gz to open afterward 
                ZipFilesG(); // GZipStream attempt 

                //** !! Must add reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem for this to work
                ZipFilesZ(); // ZipArchive attempt; this worked well for me

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };

        public void ZipFilesG()
        {
            // You may need to adjust these a bit
            string xlsFileName = "*.xlsx"; // Dts.Variables["User::ZipFileMask"].Value.ToString();
            string zipFileName = "SSIS.gz"; // Dts.Variables["User::ZipFileName"].Value.ToString();
            string zipFilePath = @"C:\TEMP\SSIS"; // Dts.Variables["User::ZipFilePath"].Value.ToString();
            string fullFilePath = zipFilePath + "\\" + zipFileName;

            MessageBox.Show($"fullFilePath: {fullFilePath}");

            //Delete the zip file
            if (File.Exists(fullFilePath)) File.Delete(fullFilePath);

            DirectoryInfo filePath = new DirectoryInfo(zipFilePath);

            try
            {
                FileStream compressedFileStream = new FileStream(fullFilePath, FileMode.Append);
                GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
                foreach (FileInfo fileToCompress in filePath.GetFiles(xlsFileName))
                {
                    using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
                    {
                        originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                    }
                }
                compressionStream.Close();
                compressedFileStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void ZipFilesZ()
        {
            // You may need to adjust these a bit
            string xlsFileName = "*.xlsx"; // Dts.Variables["User::ZipFileMask"].Value.ToString();
            string zipFileName = "SSIS.zip"; // Dts.Variables["User::ZipFileName"].Value.ToString();
            string zipFilePath = @"C:\TEMP\SSIS"; // Dts.Variables["User::ZipFilePath"].Value.ToString();
            string fullFilePath = zipFilePath + "\\" + zipFileName;

            //Delete the zip file
            if (File.Exists(fullFilePath)) File.Delete(fullFilePath);

            DirectoryInfo filePath = new DirectoryInfo(zipFilePath);

            try
            {
                foreach (FileInfo fileToCompress in filePath.GetFiles(xlsFileName))
                {
                    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(fullFilePath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                    {
                        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToCompress.FullName, fileToCompress.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have includet some references to java but ok...

Take a look at https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609927/zip-the-contents-of-a-folder-in-ssis). As others have mentioned - you're approach seems different re the Java!?

Comment: I've seen that but I dont want to hard code the arguments as I have different servers

Comment: No hard coding required :-)

Comment: But this is an SSIS package script code other task occur after it

Comment: Explain why you cannot implement the suggested answer and I will help you.